# how can i deselect a previously selected row in kivy recycleview

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

i need help deselect selected Label Item in RecycleView with SelectableLabel view.
any ideas how to solve it ?

i understand it should be written somewhere in 'def apply_selection' but im having trouble getting it to work

example:

[image: example]

i want to be able to preform another click on the selected row and that the selection will be removed.

i think the code for this should go here:

```
    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
```

i tried using a third input to specify the current selection but its not really working.
1. is this method is where i need to modify in order to achieve what im after ?
2. if so, any ideas how to do so correctly ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: edited my post, thanks for the attention

Comment: @amihai please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## FAQ

> Do you want to be able to multi-select rows, and then deselect
>   individual row? – ikolim Sep 30 '18 at 21:04
>
> no just select in one press and deselect in another press on a line
>   ,but also keep the selection changing when selecting different lines.
>   maybe its easier to say that im looking for listview behavior in this
>   recycleview – amihai Sep 30 '18 at 21:07

## Solution

The following solution is not for `multi-select`.

Set selected if row is not selected, or to deselect when it is already selected.

## Snippet

```
def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
    ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
    self.selected = not self.selected
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = not self.selected


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Selected Label 2]
[image: Img02 - Clicked on Label 8 & Label 2 auto deselected]

Comment: i was hoping to get an answer from you @ikolim , your answers always so elaborated. this doesnt quite solve my problem as i wish to be able to repress a selected row and clear that selection (in my case have no selection at all).

Comment: Do you want to be able to multi-select rows, and then deselect individual row?

Comment: no just select in one press and deselect in another press on a line ,but also keep the selection changing when selecting different lines. maybe its easier to say that im looking for listview behavior in this recycleview

Comment: just that simple .. thx again your answers here in SO are teaching me alot!

Comment: I am sorry, but multi selection is still there. Selecting a new row does not unselect the previously selected row !

Comment: @Jean-PierreSchnyder: The solution is meant for non `multi-select` as per the user's request, "Do you want to be able to multi-select rows, and then deselect individual row?", "no just select in one press and deselect in another press on a line.."

Answer (score 1):

The code below does what is asked, that is,

1. enabling only one selection at a time and
2. enabling unselecting a selected item

It is identical to the code of the first answer, except 3 differences highlighted with 
** DIFFERENCE **.

> from kivy.app import App
>   from kivy.lang import Builder
>   from
>   kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
>   from
>   kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
>   from
>   kivy.uix.label import Label
>   from kivy.properties import
>   BooleanProperty
>   from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import
>   RecycleBoxLayout
>   from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
>   from
>   kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior

```
Builder.load_string('''
<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: False # ** DIFFERENCE **
        touch_multiselect: False # ** DIFFERENCE **
''')


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

    # required to authorise unselecting a selected item
    touch_deselect_last = BooleanProperty(True) # ** DIFFERENCE **


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = not self.selected


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]


class RVMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    RVMainApp().run()
```